# Change woocommerce product names into h2

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce with flatsome theme.
I would like to add <'H2'> heading in my product names on the category pages.

Now the source code on the category pages looks like this:

```
<div class="title-wrapper"><p class="name product-title"><a href="https://www.shop.com">product-1</a></p></div>
```

I would like to change for this, or something similar:

```
<h2><div class="title-wrapper"><p class="name product-title"><a href="https://www.shop.com">product-1</a></p></div></h2>
```

Comment: Normally by default, there is already an `<h2>` tag, you can see that [on this code source](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_template_loop_product_title.html#742-747) so your Flatsome theme is making already some customizations. You should better ask in authors support as it's a premium theme.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an observation - what you want is not valid HTML. You can't have `<p>` inside `<h2>`. You will need to use `<div class="title-wrapper"><h2 class="name product-title"><a href="https://www.shop.com">product-1</a></h2></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not provided any link of your current site, I'm not able to provide you with a straight forward and specific answer.

But you can change this by editing your theme's woocommerce templates. Make sure you create a child theme first (Always a good habit so you won't lose your customization)

All you have to do is go to your filemanager if you have a cpanel or FTP and browse through the woocommerce templates which come with your theme. Then change the code as mentioned by @Peter

```
    <div class="title-wrapper"><p class="name product-title"><a href="https://www.shop.com">product-1</a></p></div>
```

TO

```
    <div class="title-wrapper"><h2 class="name product-title"><a href="https://www.shop.com">product-1</a></h2></div>
```

If you cannot find it, You can give me your site URL and I will provide you a specific solution of what to do.